# Spring Boot does not throw HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

There is a simple loginController with loginRequest annotated with @RequestBody

```java
@RestController
public class LoginController{
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> doLogin(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, BindingResult bindingResult){
    }
}
// ...

public class LoginRequest {

    @NotBlank(message = "Email/Phone Can not be empty")
    private String emailAddressOrPhoneNumber;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password Can not be empty")
    private String password;

    public LoginRequest() {
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

I am testing this code via `WebMvcTest` like this one:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = LoginController.class)
public class LoginControllerMvcTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        NewCustomerRequest invalidRequestType = // assume that there is a valid new customer object.
        MvcResult mvcResultForInvalidRequestType = mockMvc.perform("/login")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(invalidRequestType))
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
// ...
public class NewCustomerRequest {
    @NotBlank(message = "Email can not be empty")
    @EmailValueValidation
    private String emailAddress;

    @PhoneNumberRegexValidation
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password can not be empty")
    @InvalidPasswordCharacterValidation
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password verify can not be empty")
    @InvalidPasswordCharacterValidation
    private String passwordVerify;
```

What I would like to see is that spring throws the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` because i am trying to make Login request with different json type.

However, request comes to the controller with these values:

```java
loginRequest.emailAddressOrPhoneNumber = null
loginRequest.passsword = "passwordFromNewCustomerRequest"
```

How do I force the Spring throws the Exception in that case?

Comment: If you do not set anything in the content , spring will throw HttpMessageNotReadableException  MvcResult mvcResultForInvalidRequestType = mockMvc.perform("/login")
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn();

Comment: Spring should throw exception after i send the NewCustomerRequest. Otherwise, it will be the another case (not sending content for example)

Comment: did you maybe forget `@Validated` on top of your controller class? See https://rieckpil.de/spring-web-mvc-cheat-sheet/#how-can-i-validate-the-incoming-payload-to-my-controller

Comment: @rieckpil, it did not work for me. I read the section about @Validated and added to the my loginController class.  I also set this property `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true` , but this one also did not work